# Swing lintel load with shorter string?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

**The Question**: If I make the RED strings slightly shorter (what holds the swings) than the GREEN strings, would that mean that the RED "X" will have more weight/load vs. the GREEN "X"?

Just want to avoid load on the center of the top "lintel" to avoid deflection since it would be better if the side RED "X"es would take more load, since they are more robust vs. the center of the top "lintel".

I know it probably doesn't changes the distribution of the load, just loud thinking, how to reduce the load from the center of the lintel..

Comment: I would suggest using chains or ropes rather than strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two supporting chains on each side of a seat swing are not equal in length, the swing will “wobble” when in motion. (The period of a pendulum depends on it length.) Also, the seat would not be level if the lengths are not the same. In any case, the center of support (when at rest) will always be above the center of gravity.